# Как передать UTM-метки в Android приложение?

Tags: android, webview

У сайта есть Android приложение (WebView), нужно чтобы параметры ссылок на GP вида:

play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myapp.com&referrer=utm_medium%3Dmetka

передавались на сайт, т.е. ссылка, которая открывается в приложении после установки, была бы такой:

site.ru/?utm_medium=metka

Comment: Не очень ясно что у вас есть и что вы хотите сделать. Сделаю предположение - у вас приложение, в нём webView и вы переходите в нём по ссылкам, в которых нет желаемых вами параметров и вы хотите их добавить, не меняя сайт, но изменяя ссылки в WebView из мобильного приложения, в котором это WebView находится?

Comment: Не совсем... у меня приложение, в нём webView. Гугл вроде как позволяет передавать UTM-метки, по которым перешли в магазин приложений Google Play и оттуда установили его, в мое приложение.

Comment: Т.е., чтобы эта метка передавалась в webView, и вместо дефолтного site.ru/ там открывалась ссылка с меткой - site.ru/?utm_medium=metka.. вроде этого, наверное - https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer

Comment: Ну, судя по вашей же ссылке такое есть. Используйте инструкцию к либе (https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/library) и вы получите информацию нужную. Дальше её надо будет вручную передать в WebView. Само оно туда передаться никак не может.